# How do I use a shell script to look through directories and alter files?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, ftp, directory

I've crafted a script that does 90% of what I'm looking to do. It goes into a directory (based on the entered date) and it changes the files I feed into the array. However, I want to alter this script to also contain an array of dates (which are the directory names). It will cycle through the directories, when it finds one of the files from the file name array, it corrects it and moves on until all the files have been corrected. I've tried a few different versions of this, but I am not sure how to implement a second array to continue looking through directories after a file has been corrected.

Currently, my script looks like this:

```
debug=false

## *****Put file name in quotes******
declare -a arr=("UF19905217" "UG19905218" )

##Put date in DDMMYYYY format for the date the message was original processed.
DATE="25082015"

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    #if "$debug; then
        echo "Fix file named: Inbound_$i.msg"
        MSG="Inbound_$i.msg"
    #fi

    if [ ! -d "$MSG" ]; then
    # Enter what you would like changed here.  You can copy and paste this command for multiple changes

        #DATATYPE
        printf "%s\n" ',s/<DataType>EDI<\/DataType>/<DataType>830<\/DataType>/g' wq | ed -s  /data1/Inbound/$DATE/$MSG        

        echo "Complete"
    else
            echo "Message not found or errored!"
    fi

done
```

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't seen `ed` used in a while. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want to enclose the loop you have in a loop that iterates over the desired directories:

```
debug=false

## *****Put file name in quotes******
declare -a arr=("UF19905217" "UG19905218" )

##Put date in DDMMYYYY format for the date the message was original processed.
dates=( 25082015 26082015 )

for DATE in "${dates[@]}"; do    
  for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    MSG="Inbound_$i.msg"
    if $debug; then
      echo "Fix file named: $MSG"
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$MSG" ]; then
      printf "%s\n" ',s/<DataType>EDI<\/DataType>/<DataType>830<\/DataType>/g' wq | ed -s  /data1/Inbound/$DATE/$MSG
      echo "Complete"
    else
      echo "Message not found or errored!"
    fi
  done
done
```